# SSRS Chart: Comparing set with subset

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart

I am trying to accomplish something with a chart.

My dataset contains 100 rows of paper submissions. Each paper submission has a SubmissionStatus of "Logged." Not all of the papers were accepted, however, so only thirty papers have a FinalDispositionStatus of "Accepted;" the rest have a FinalDispositionStatus of "Rejected." Each paper also has a CategoryID associated with it (there are 5 possible categories).

What I'd like my chart to do is to show, for each CategoryID, how many papers were submitted (SubmissionStatus = Logged) and how many papers were accepted (FinalDispositionStatus = Accepted).

I envision a bar chart. Along the bottom X-axis, I would have CategoryIDs 1-5. For each category, there would be two bars. One bar represents the total number of submissions against that category. The other bar represents the total number of Accepted Submissions against that category. I do not want to show the Rejected submissions on the chart.

Any suggestions you could offer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a basic report with a simplified version of your Dataset:

[image]

Based on this I added a Bar Chart to the report:

[image]

The most import thing to note is that I've added two values to the data fields section, one based on the expression:

`=Count(Fields!FinalDispositionStatus.Value)`

Which gives the number of submitted papers per category, and one with the expression:

`=Sum(IIf(Fields!FinalDispositionStatus.Value = "Accepted", 1, 0))`

Which gives the number of accepted papers per category.

Make sure to set the Category field value to `=Fields!categoryId.Value` and set the Custom legend text appropriately for the two data fields!

End result:

[image]

You can see it's a bit rough but working as required.

This was tested in SSRS 2008.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Let me look at what you've done and respond back.

Comment: Very awesome. Thank you for helping me understand the structure of what I was supposed to be doing. You taught me how to fish!